# Can't set NSUserDefaults value through variable in IOS

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

In my iOS app when I'm logging in I used set UserID and *loginstatus* into `NSUserDefaults` like this.

```
@implementation Login{
    NSInteger UserId;
    NSUserDefaults *preferences;
}

- (IBAction)LogInClick:(UIButton *)sender {

 [preferences setInteger:UserId forKey:@"UserId"]; //UserId=40;
 [preferences setBool:YES forKey:@"loginstatus"];
 [preferences synchronize];

 NSLog(@"All NSUserDefaults: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);

 NSString *uID = [preferences stringForKey:@"UserId"];
 NSLog(@"UserID: %@",uID);
}
```

But the values are not setting in the NSUserDefaults. I tried to log all NSUserDefaults value and also the single UserID value but all fields are coming null.

Later I use this code to logout

```
  - (IBAction)LogOutClick:(UIButton *)sender {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:0 forKey:@"UserId"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:NO forKey:@"loginstatus"];

   /* [preferences setInteger:0 forKey:@"UserId"];
    [preferences setBool:NO forKey:@"loginstatus"];
    [preferences synchronize];*/

    NSLog(@"All NSUserDefaults: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

}

First when i logged out it all sets to zero and now the values are not setting. Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `NSUserDefaults *preferences;` is just a pointer. And it's value is `nil`, I presume. You should initialize it. For instance:

```
- (IBAction)LogInClick:(UIButton *)sender {
   preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   [preferences setInteger:UserId forKey:@"UserId"]; //UserId=40;
   [preferences setBool:YES forKey:@"loginstatus"];
   [preferences synchronize];
 ...
```

May be a more logical place to initialize `preferences` would be an `init` method, or something else that you would consider appropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't get the standard userdefaults reference. Change this method

```
- (IBAction)LogInClick:(UIButton *)sender {

  preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 [preferences setInteger:UserId forKey:@"UserId"]; //UserId=40;
 [preferences setBool:YES forKey:@"loginstatus"];
 [preferences synchronize];

 NSLog(@"All NSUserDefaults: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);

 NSString *uID = [preferences stringForKey:@"UserId"];
 NSLog(@"UserID: %@",uID);
}
```